# jQuery UI Bounce for progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, animation

How would i add jQuery's UI Bounce feature to this script? The script currently slides out a progress bar to a set position. I would like that when it reaches the position it bounces back and forth a few times and then rests.

I tried a few previous stack overflow answers but none of them work.

```
    $(function () {
$(".meter .bar").each(function () {
    $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
        width: $(this).data("origWidth")
    }, 900);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It uses an object after the CSS mods in `animate()` to set the properties.

You can use `bounce` just change the direction in options.

```
$(function () {
    $(".meter .bar").each(function () {

        $(this).data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
            }, 700)
            .effect('bounce', {times: 3, 
                              direction: "right", 
                              distance: 10}
                    , 700);
    });
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk2vZ/4/)

Comment: Thats after removing one of the bars from the screen

Comment: @Exhausted Ok the bounce effect works! Hopefully that's what you want. I can understand why you're exhausted.

Comment: consistently a drain on society and resources - like a pro ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a hack,  check whether it is acceptable.

Because in order to use the `bounce` animation we need to call `show` on a hidden item, check whether the blinking effect is acceptable, then you can use it.

Try using the animate callback

```
$(function() {
    $(".meter .bar").each(function() {
        $(this).data("origWidth", $(this).width()).width(0)
            .animate({
                width : $(this).data("origWidth")
                }, 900, function(){
                    $(this).effect("bounce", {
            times:3,
            direction: 'right'
                    });
        });
     });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzjzBgCNJo1TO4LgzUDp?p=preview) 
Demo: [Effect](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kc89gLz57sUXNk6R7Wiq?p=preview)

Comment: Its bouncing.. but not exactly how i hoped. I want them to bounce off of their final position after they slide (bounce from right to left) - see link

[link](http://music.insanitypop.com/bars.html)

Comment: In that case you case check the `shake` effect, check the updated solution

Comment: Still not there, sorry for pestering you Arun. How would i add gravity to that? Imagine it was a ball hitting the ground. when it hits it would bounce to a certain height, fall again and bounce to a lesser height and it would do this a few times until rest.

Thats why i thought it was jQuery UI's bounce effect. Because it seems to have gravity (see [link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce#demo)

Comment: Yea that blinking is going to piss me off. I might just use the bounce effect and skip my original js.

Thanks for your help